# How would you export Javadoc as a .jar file in Eclipse?

Tags: java, javadoc

I'm finally done with my project, JConsole Maker. I put all the Javadoc comments in and I'm ready to export the Javadoc. I just don't know how. I can do it into a folder, but is there any specific way to export it to a .jar so Eclipse developers can use it too?

Answer (score 3):

My answers does not correspond exactly what you're asking but here is a way to build a .jar of your project (JConsole Maker) with associated javadoc:
Once you have generated the javadoc into a folder, do

File > Export...> Java > Jar File  and check "Export Java source files and resources".

Then your javadoc will be associated with your whole project.
Please notice that your sources files will also be included...